# How to add more data to tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out how to get extra text to popup on the tooltip. I want the tooltip to include a quantity remaining number. I know it has something to do with referencing `point.this`. I've tried bracket notation like:

```
data: [{x:'Spiderman',y:3.7,desc:'d1'}, {x:'Darth Vader',y:15.0,desc:'d2'}, {x:'Mickey Mouse',y:34.67,desc:'d3'}, {x:'Luke Skywalker',y:32.4,desc:'d4'}, {x:'Buck Rogers',y:13.0,desc:'d5'}, {x:'Ace Ventura',y:5.9,desc:'d5'}, {x:'Captain Marvel',y:23.4,desc:'d5'}]
```

but that didn't work, and I'm unfamiliar with it.  Does anyone know how to add extra text?

Here's my HighChart: https://jsfiddle.net/tbxg5s4y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store additional data in `custom` property and depending on your needs, refer to them in `tooltip.pointFormat` or `tooltip.formatter`.

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: 'y: {point.y}<br>desc: {point.custom.desc}<br>quantity: {point.custom.quantity}'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      name: 'Spiderman',
      y: 3.7,
      custom: {
        desc: 'd1',
        quantity: 1
      }
    }, ...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lepsa58w/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.custom

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat